# Unable to load DLL 'SIMDArrayInstructions.dll'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

Here's the problem: placing the SIMDArrayInstructions.dll in my asp.net application's bin/ folder works just fine while developing, but when I deploy the application to the web server, I receive a System.DllNotFoundException with the message:

`Unable to load DLL 'SIMDArrayInstructions.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

This occurs even when the .dll is present in the bin/ folder.

What is going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to load DLL (Module could not be found HRESULT: 0x8007007E)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003072/unable-to-load-dll-module-could-not-be-found-hresult-0x8007007e)

Answer (score 0):

The solution, I found, was to install the corresponding Visual C++ Redistributable for the version of SIMDArrayInstructions on the given server.

You can use a program like http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to analyze the dll and determine what may be missing.

Comment: C++ 2010 Redistributable in particular.