# PDF viewer extension for Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, pdf, extension-methods

Is there any free PDF viewer extension for Windows Forms that has no limitations for the number of pages or having one PDF viewer installed on your computer? I saw Free Spire.PDFViewer for .NET but it has limitation for 10 pages max.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions of installing Adobe Acrobat Reader on the host machine?

Comment: No, I am building an application for commercial use so I want to have a PDF reader already there if some customer doesn't have any PDF reader installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [PdfiumViewer](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer)?, it provides a control to render pdf on winforms

Comment: Is this just a library or could I use it as a tool(drag and drop it like buttons..etc)

Comment: It has two controls to use with winforms, need to refer to the documentation as the controls have some built-in functionality.

Comment: Actually this is a great article and code. I ran .exe and it worked perfectly but when I implement it in my app i get an exception that 'pdfium.dll' could not be found and unable to load 'pdfium.dll'.

Comment: System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'pdfium.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

Comment: Make sure that the dll can be loaded by your executable, one alternative is to place the dll in your bin/debug or bin/release folders in your solution.

Comment: Yes, it is in x64 and x86 folders and still get the exception. I don't know what's the problem

Comment: Check if the solutions proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003072/unable-to-load-dll-module-could-not-be-found-hresult-0x8007007e work for you

Comment: I've figured it out. You have to set Copy to Output directory to Copy Always.

Comment: Thank you @james_bond for your help :)

Comment: No problem, please upvote and mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I did. Not enough reputation for marking though.