# An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format - only when published in the hoster

Tags: asp.net, dll

I have a C# asp.net Project that calls a .dll file made in C++. Running locally in my computer, it works well. But, when publishing it on line in my web site hoster, there is an error: “An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)”.

I found similar problem in other thread, but after many attempt I did not work.

[Unable to load DLL (Module could not be found HRESULT: 0x8007007E)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003072/unable-to-load-dll-module-could-not-be-found-hresult-0x8007007e)

Note that the problem only happens after publishing the project and saving the files in my web site hoster. Some links showing my setup.

[Link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQxBl.png); [Link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IqXi.png); [Link3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a0Ft.png)

I am not sure if there is any relation, but before that I was having the problem: “Unable to load DLL (Module could not be found HRESULT: 0x8007007E)”. Using “dependency walker”, I identified some missing dll files (such as: kernel32.dll, ntdll.dll, vcruntime140d.dll...) I and added them in the on-line bin folder. Then, I started having the problem I first mentioned.

I continued the investigation and realised I was using a dll created by debug. Then I used the one created by release, and then I have again the error “Unable to load DLL (Module could not be found HRESULT: 0x8007007E)”. Using “dependency walker”, there is huge list of dll files, see link4. Not sure if it makes sense, because the list is long. Any help? [Link4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLM5G.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing the search, the problem was solved by including DLL files from the Visual Studio installation folder, in my case: 
*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC*
More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx