# Google OR-Tools HRESULT: 0x8007007E on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012-r2, or-tools

I created a windows service application that uses Google OR-Tools library for Net. I successfully tested it on local dev environent - Windows 10 (x64).

However when I move that application to Windows Server 2012 R2, it throws following error:

```
Knihovnu DLL Google.OrTools.runtime.win-x64.dll nelze načíst: Uvedený modul nebyl nalezen. (Výjimka na základě hodnoty HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
Inicializační metoda typu SWIGExceptionHelper vyvolala výjimku.
Inicializační metoda typu Google.OrTools.Sat.operations_research_satPINVOKE vyvolala výjimku.
```

It's in czech, however I think important is **HRESULT: 0x8007007E**

I tried following according to another questions on SO:

- checked, that OR-tools libraries are in application directory
- added application directory to PATH variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio from here: https://support.microsoft.com/cs-cz/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

**The one matching your version of Visual Studio** that was used for compilation (according to https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/35)

For further reference, see this SO: [Unable to load DLL (Module could not be found HRESULT: 0x8007007E)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003072/unable-to-load-dll-module-could-not-be-found-hresult-0x8007007e)