# How to fix Error HRESULT 0x8007007E on windows 10 x64

Tags: c#, dllimport

I created an x86 application with Visual Studio 2019 under Windows 7 x64 which is based on two programming languages ​​C# and C++.
I created DLLs in C++ after I imported them into the C# project from the menu: Build dependencies> Project dependencies.
Not only that, but I added all the DLL dependencies in the same folder where my EXE is located.
The problem is that my application works very well under Windows 7 X64 but on Windows 10 I have the HRESULT error.
In windows10 i don't have visuel studio installed. it's a test machine.

> An unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click
> continue. the application will ignore this error and try to continue.
> If you click Exit, the application will stop immediately. Unable to
> load UserTrack. DLL the specified module could not be found (Exception
> from HRESULT 0x8007007E.

I have tried looking for the dll from absolute path in DLLIMPORT function. i installed also x86: vc_redist.x86.exe
and x64: vc_redist.x64.exe to fix the problem.

But Nothing help, always i get the error as above.

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: Problem with Windows 10 Updates mostly. What the application seems to fail to load libraries. What you could do is run application from Visual Studio look for debugging stacktrace/logs.

Comment: Suggestions here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003072/unable-to-load-dll-module-could-not-be-found-hresult-0x8007007e

Comment: Forgetting to *also* deploy the dependencies that the C++ dll needs is a common oversight.  Tends to work by accident on a dirty machine, no such luck on a clean one.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

Comment: I think that it's better to take a look at Dependency Walker (both versions , x86 and x64) and import your main exe file in it, and it loads all dependencies and alert you if you have mismatch in your reference dlls. also nested dlls