# System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'canusbdrv64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dllimport, can-bus

I am trying to run an application in C# for CAN USB. I am running it on multiple laptops and it is running successfully. But it is giving me problems on two new laptops. The error is

```
System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'canusbdrv64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried all the solutions that are available that placing file on system32, main application folder (bin/Debug) but it is not able to find the dll. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You also have a dependency on FTD2XX.dll, if it is missing then you'll get this error.

Comment: I installed and checked. No success

Comment: Is the OS the same on the different PCs? Maybe the DLL has other dependencies that it cannot load (like @HansPassant mentioned). Try to analyze dependencies using for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25685000 or try dependency walker (https://www.dependencywalker.com/). Also, it seems the module is 64-bits and you're running with AnyCPU, maybe try using x64 as the target platform.