# Registration-Free COM from ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, com, manifest, regfreecom

Windows allows use of a COM object [without having to register the COM dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx).

The mechanism is to include a "*dependent assembly*" in the application's manifest:

> **MyProgram.exe.manifest**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
> <assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
>   <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="myapp.exe" version="1.2.3.4" />
>   <dependency>
>     <dependentAssembly>
>       <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Contoso.Frobber" version="5.1.81.4" />
>     </dependentAssembly>
>   </dependency>
> </assembly>
> ```

And then your folder contains:

- `MyProgram.exe`
- `MyProgram.exe.manifest` (if you're using an external manifest; could also be embedded at `RT_MANIFEST` resource)
- `Contoso.Frobber.manifest` (the COM DLL manifest)
- `confrob.dll` (the dll containing the COM classes we want to use)

with the COM dll's assembly manifest containing:

> **Contoso.Frobber.manifest**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
> <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
>
>    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Contoso.Frobber" version="1.0.0.0" />
>
>    <file name = "confrob.dll">
>
>       <comClass
>             progid="Frobber.Gizmo"
>             clsid="{00028C00-0000-0000-0000-000000000046}"
>             description="Gizmo Frobber by Contoso"
>             threadingModel = "Apartment" />
>
>       <typelib 
>             tlbid="{00028C01-0000-0000-0000-000000000046}"
>             version="1.0" 
>             helpdir=""/>
>    </file>
> </assembly>
> ```

Excellent. i can now use a COM object from a (native or .NET) executable without having to register the COM object.

Now i want to use a COM object from **an ASP.NET web-site**, without registering the COM object.

Possible?

---

### Bonus Chatter

Windows also allows an [exe to call a .NET library, without having to install the .NET assembly into the Global Assembly Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973915.aspx).

Comment: What makes you think it's not possible?

Comment: @RB The program that wants to depend on an unregistered DLL needs to declare that dependancy in it's manifest (`MyProgram.exe.manifest` in my original example). In the case of ASP.NET, the program that i would have to manfiest is `w3wp.exe`, creating `w3wp.exe.manifest` and place it in `Program Files`. i shouldn't be manifesting *all* www worker processes; i only want to manifest my "web-site". And i see no way to *"manifest a web-site"*.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. This is an old DAO-based visual control, so at best you might use it client-side in its unbound mode. Reg-free COM does not apply and isn't required. There is a way to load such an ActiveX control in IE via the <object> tag from a CAB file on your site, as long as you create and specify a license package (LPK) file for the page too. Even this assumes relaxed security in IE though.

Comment: `dbgrid32.ocx` was only an example to help people understand what registration-free COM is used for. i will replace `dbgrid32.ocx` with the filename i'm actually using. It doesn't change the question or the concepts - although might make it more difficult for people to understand what i'm asking.

Comment: Perhaps you can dig an answer out of this: [Isolating ASP .Net 2.0 Applications](http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxs/help/iis6aspnet2.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently we were handling a similar case that we needed to enable Side by Side COM(reg-free COM) in IIS hosted ASP.NET core application, and we made it like:

1. embed the manifest to an assembly(.dll)
2. use CreateActCtx() to activate the manifest.

This approach works fine and it's recommended by MS .NET Runtime Interop Team.

Answer (score 3):

Although I can't test it right now I am pretty sure that this works:

IF the manifest for a DLL is external it will usually be ignored when the DLL is loaded via `LoadLibrary` (according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235512.aspx)). IF the manifest is embedded into the DLL it is usually honored.

Embed the manifest into the ASP.NET application (i.e. code-behind DLL) - for some ways on how to do this see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917710/847363) and [here](http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxs/help/iis6aspnet2.htm).

UPDATE - as per comments:

The above is a workaround as there is no general way to do this (isolation), at least the ASP.NET creators haven't intended this to be possible - for example the above workaround won't work in cases where the application does not compile to a DLL...

Comment: i would really rather not modify the global `asp.net.dll`. Aside from it likely being a protected file, which cannot be modified, invaliding it's security signature, using [a global solution to solve a local problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx), it would mean that i could not have different web-sites isolated with different versions of the COM dll (e.g. Live and Test)

Comment: If asp.net web-sites cannot use any of the Windows mechanisms for isloation - then that's the answer. Don't be afraid to say, "No, it cannot be done. ASP.net doesn't support isolated binaries."

Comment: @IanBoyd I am NOT talking about the global `asp.net.dll` - I would strongly advise against doing that! My recommendation was to modify YOUR ASP.NET application which is itself a DLL which in turn loads/uses the COM component if I understand your scenario correctly...

Comment: @IanBoyd As I wrote above: I can't test this currently... but I would think it is possible as described (putting the manifest into your application/code-behind DLL)...

Comment: @IanBoyd updated my answer to clarify this point explicitely.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense. Although it only would work for web-sites that compile to an assembly dll. i think the better answer is, "Cannot be done" - since the designers of ASP.net have no intended way to support isolation.