# In C#, is it possible to Impersonate as an admin user and Run another program with Admin privileges without it asking for a password? - SOLVED

Tags: c#, prompt, impersonation, uac, admin-rights

The tech team doesn't want to give all the users admin rights on the machines.
But still those same users should be able to update by themselves one software.
So, inside of this software, it should launch another one with admin rights.
They will set one admin user that will have admin rights on all the machines. Then the code should use this admin user and it's password to impersonate as an admin. So it should launch the update software as another user.

I tried to do it, but it still asks for a user and password when I try to run things with admin rights.
I've checked and System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; returns the user admin username inside the code. So it is indeed impersonating this another user.

The question is, is it even possible inside windows?
How can it run as admin, and only appear the UAC prompt, without it asking for a user and a password?

I'm impersonating with this

```
SafeAccessTokenHandle safeAccessTokenHandle;  
bool returnValue = LogonUser(user, domain, password,  
LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,  
out safeAccessTokenHandle);
```

Then running the other process this way.

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    var output = WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync(  
        safeAccessTokenHandle,                  
        async () =>  
        {                        
            try 
            {           
                return await RunProcessAsync("XYZ.exe","", true);
                
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        } 
    ).Result;
}


static Task<int> RunProcessAsync(string fileName, string arguments = "", bool runAsAdmin = false)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = { FileName = fileName, Arguments = arguments, UseShellExecute = true, LoadUserProfile = true },
        EnableRaisingEvents = true                  
    };

    if (runAsAdmin) process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    
    process.Exited += (sender, args) =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(process.ExitCode);
        process.Dispose();
    };            
    process.Start();

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

I tried to impersonate as an Admin user
Then run another program with Admin privilegs, and all the user would have to do is agree with the UAC prompt.
I was expecting to be able to run without it asking for user and password, but it still asked anyway.

EDIT - 1

It seems to have worked, somehow this code would not work if called from a .net framework application. It would still ask for a login and password.
But it will work if you call from a .NET 6 application. It will then impersonate as a admin, then it will only do a UAC prompt for yes or no.

EDIT - 2

Some windows policies are needed in order for this to work.

1. User needs impersonation permission. "Impersonate client after authentication.", logged user needs to be there.
2. Without the permission prompt, it won't work. "User control account: Run All Administrators in Admin Approval Mode" needs to be enabled.
   Without this prompt, the application will give a "not enough memory" error.

Comment: You need a background service running as SYSTEM that can start off the update process.

Comment: ...or  desktop management software running on the clients that you can  control to automate the updates instead of having users do it manaully.

Comment: If it were possible to impresonate an admin without its password, user accounts wouldn't have any real value or provide any security.

Comment: Thank you Charlieface, I will try the background service route.
 
Dave S, I don't think the tech team will want to handle this.

Alejandro, that's why I'm impersonating as an admin, inside the code I'm passing the user, domain and password. I just wanted a way to make windows think the user that is running the code is the admin.

Comment: _The tech team doesn't want to give all the users admin rights on the machines. But still those same users should be able to update by themselves one software_: This is an instance of wanting to _have one's cake and eat it too_. Based on the IT support structure that you've described. The IT support team will need to perform the software updates using the tools at their disposal.

Comment: There are tools available to IT/infrastructure teams to do this (push updates to local PCs without local users' involvement). Going that route (using tested and supported mechanisms) is the right way to do this. Writing a service to do this is a very good way of introducing a security whole in your systems.

Comment: Problem is, they want to save money. Up until now they were using a desktop virtualization server, so all the updates were done in the server. Now they want to save money, shut down this desktop virtualization server, and run everything locally.

Comment: They rejected the idea of implementing a service.

But I guess I managed to make it work. But everything is still hardcoded, I still don't know how things will work in an production enviroment.

For some reason if I try to impersonate and launch another task as admin from a .net framework executable, it won't work.

But, if I launch from the .net framework as a non admin another .net core exe. Then in this .net core I impersonate as admin, and run another .exe as a admin. Then it will work.

This task that is running as admin is visually all messed, but it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

> The tech team doesn't want to give all the users admin rights on the machines. But still those same users should be able to update by themselves one software.

- If you want to allow any user to be able to update your application
- then grant all **Users** permission to modify the contents of the folder

[image]

This is the kind of action your installer is supposed to perform while it has admin access during installation.

- In reality they don't need **Full Control** (i.e. they don't need permission to change permissions on the folder)
- they can get by with **Modify**

This is what **Microsoft** did with **World of Warcraft**; they created an app-compat shim that grants everyone permission to **Modify** the **World of Warcraft** folder. This way the 12-year old is able to get their game updates.

[image]

Comment: Problem is, the setup needs permission to run the regsvr32 in order to add the dlls to the registry. Also it may add dlls to the SySWow64 folder. And also it updates some entries on the registry for all the users.

Comment: - register your COM objects in HKCU rather than HKLM, or use [Registration-free COM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9162817/12597) so you don't have to register the COM objects in the global registry at all (preferred). Set the ACL on the certain registry keys in HKLM during install that allows all users the ability to modify those registry keys.

Comment: Alternatively, ensure that file and folder virtualization remains on (by omitting `requestedExecutionLevel` manifest entry complete), so that when your application tries to write to HKLM it will be silently redirected to the correct location in HKCU.

Comment: If it is registered in HKCU, will it work with any user that logs into the machine? There are around 400 files (.dll and .ocx).

Comment: It will work with any user on the machine as long as you re-register it under that user. The better approach is to use registration-free COM; so there is no registering at all.