Use GoLang DLL with VB application on Windows
I am working with an existing VB application that allows plugins to be imported as DLLs on Windows 11. I am told that the language used to create the DLL plugin does not matter.
I am a fan of GoLang and so I tried to create a very simple DLL to see if I could import it as a plugin.
The GoLang DLL looks like this:

package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export Hello
func Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from DLL!")
}

func main() {}

The compilation command I use is this:

go -o mydll.dll -buildmode=c-shared

However, when I try to load the plugin into the VB app, I get this error:
.NET DLL Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\testing\mydll.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. UM DLL Exception: ImageRvaToVa (NamesPointer) failed
I have not found any solutions to this so far on Google. How can I use my GoLang DLL with the VB app?
I was expecting to load my GoLang DLL into the VB app as a plugin.
UPDATE:
Interestingly using mt.exe seems to do nothing. It does not change the size or modification time of the dll:
> .\mt.exe -manifest "App.config" -outputresource:"mydll.dll"
> .\mt.exe -inputresource:"mydll.dll" -out:"my.extracted.manifest"


Is the VB application a 32 or 64 bit executable? If it is a 32bit application you also need to create 32bit dll files as plugin. How to add a .net manifest to your dll see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1899535/150978

Thanks for the comment and link. It is a 64-bit executable. I checked out the link. I see how to add the manifest, could you suggest how I create a manifest?

The linked answer contains a command to extract a manifest from an exe/dll file. If you have a different plugin try to extract its manifest and adapt it for your dll.

It sounds like your VB app is expecting your plug-in dlls to be .NET assemblies, but doesn't golang produce native code?

What documentation is there for the VB plugin interface?
